# facebook Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I try to send respond message on facebook as response

```
    $replay_message = '{
    "messaging_type": "RESPONSE",
    "recipient": {
      "id": "'.$id.'"
    },
    "message": {
      "text": "Hello , We are Offline now! We will sent replay to : '.$messasge.'"
    }
}';

send_replay($access_token , $replay_message);

function send_replay($access_token = "" , $replay = "")
{
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/me/messages?access_token=".$access_token;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $replay);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $result = json_decode($output , true);
    file_put_contents('text.txt' , $output);
    return $result;
}
```

when i get token from developer.facebook.com is work fine but from login with this request :

```
email,public_profile,pages_messaging,pages_manage_metadata,pages_show_list,ads_management
```

give me this :

```
   "error":{
  "message":"Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/graph-api",
  "type":"GraphMethodException",
  "code":100,
  "error_subcode":33,
  "fbtrace_id":"AxJcSLQzHGkf0-FecpYMa7O"
```

}

Comment: Sounds like you are using the wrong kind of token. The alias `me` should resolve fine for user or page tokens, but of course only using a page token makes sense here, cause only pages can send messages via API.

Comment: thanks you save my day the token i was used is user token i change it with page token and everything is working fine :)